# adsense ads not showing up on site

Tags: adsense

Hmm ...  not sure why, but adsense ads aren't showing up on this site (http://dapperhawk.com). The code is exactly the same as is provided on the adsense site as far as I can tell:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
        google_ad_client = "ca-pub-1773904113940189";
        /* bottom_results */
        google_ad_slot = "0900749086";
        google_ad_width = 468;
        google_ad_height = 60;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
```

Any thoughts on how one might troubleshoot this?

Comment: may be this helps you http://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=10036

Comment: Ahh, I should have mentioned I went through those. Don't have adblock installed. the adsense code was added a while back and was working at one point. There's no shady content on the site, and I don't believe I violate any policies.

Comment: :) yep.I have seen the page source and it was perfectly clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to follow up on this ... I sent an email to google support, and got a response that essentially said, "it looks like it's working now". I didn't change anything :-/